# C# How can I clear the memory usage?

Tags: c#, csv, memory-management, datagridview

This code exports csv file from datagridview. Occasionally getting issues with memory usage, when exported data gets larger than 1k columns and 10k rows.
There is increased memory usage on Task Manager, even after usage of dispose() and flush() in code.
What I exactly want is to add a row in CSV file and refresh the memory.Add a row and refresh memory each time.
How can I solve this problem?
I have already used GC, without change in results.

```
private void export_csv_file()
    {
        SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "csv file (*.csv)|*.csv";
        dialog.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss") + "_R";

        String csvFile;
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            csvFile = dialog.FileName;
            StreamWriter sw_column = new StreamWriter(File.Open(csvFile, FileMode.Create), Encoding.Default);
            // write columns to csv file
            //m_gridView has a datatable
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in m_gridView.Columns)
            {
                sw_column.Write(col.Name + ",");
            }
            sw_column.Write("\r\n");
            sw_column.Dispose();
            sw_column.Close();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in m_gridView.Rows)
            {
                StreamWriter sw_row = new StreamWriter(File.Open(csvFile, FileMode.Append), Encoding.Default);

                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    sw_row.Write(cell.Value + ",");
                }

                sw_row.Write("\r\n");
                sw_row.Dispose();
                sw_row.Close();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(500);
            this.Activate();
        }
        dialog.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Can you have a look at this link, not from grid, but it does pretty much same work.
Exported half million rows in less than 2 mins.

https://www.codeproject.com/questions/454679/export-large-datatable-data-to-csv-file-in-csharp

Also, my personal experience says that using StringBuilder instead of StreamnWriter will help.
Apply size check and keep dumping into file.

Comment: It is hard to see exactly what the problem is. Do the problem go away once the method is done? Some points:
- There is no need to create a new StreamWriter per row. One should be plenty
- The memory consumption in Task Manager is not a good metric. Windows will only force a GC if the available memory is low (<5% or so)

Comment: try defining the streamwriter with the **using** keyword so that it disposes itself. you can find some samples here:https://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter

Comment: The problem is that you want to store all results in the gridview and then saving to a file. You should stream the data from the database (sqlreader) and save it per row.

Comment: Can you show how you fill the grid?

Comment: program read data from specific files, make a data table by compare items(columns) that I selected. And last, add to datagridview by mydatagridview.datasource = mydatatable;

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Also making datagridview process increase the memory usage, but I thought the problem is different. I found that there is no matter with streamwriter.

Comment: @장헌수 can you show how you read the files? Storing the data in a DataTable and binding it to a datagrid view, is very 'expensive'.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I can't explain how exactly read the files. Only I know is I have meta and tm files. And when I set the file path, the program make the file list, read the files in the list and make information from them, kind of records. This program has memory usage problem and I have to fix it not to increase the memory when I export it to a csv file.

Comment: You're export function in not the problem, your import function is. So we can't help you at this moment.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Ok, I got it. I'll check it. Thank you for your reply and advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try refactoring your code with this format, although as @Jeroen van Langen points out, the problem might lay on the way you use the datasource

UPDATE: since you pointed out you first load the data into a **DataTable**...

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //Your datasource
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "csv file (*.csv)|*.csv";
sfd.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss") + "_R";

if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName))
    {
        //Add Column Headers
        sw.Write(string.Join(",", dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName)));
        sw.Write(",\r\n");

        //Add Rows
        foreach (var row in dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.ItemArray.Cast<string>()))
        {
            sw.Write(string.Join(",", row));
            sw.Write(",\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried your suggestion and  sw.BaseStream.Close(); and sw.BaseStream.Dispose(); but nothing changed.

Comment: And also the way that I use datasource and making datagridview increase the memory usage but the export process also increase the memory usage.

Comment: @장헌수 I updated the code to write the data directly from a datatable

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this and let you know result.

Comment: You are correct. I can't watch increase of memory usage. Thanks for your help!